# If and switch statement results not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a small javascript program that will do 3 things, 1. it will determine if a number is odd or even and display that result on the webpage, 2. calculate a letter grade based on a number entered on the webpage via a switch statement, and 3. reset the form based on the press of the button.

The odd and even part and reset part seem to work ok but the grade switch statement is not working.  It doesn't seem to be displaying the letter grade that corresponds to the value entered.  I tried looking at the error but have not had much luck.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>WDV221 Intro Javascript</title>
        <script src="Odd_Even_Grades.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>WDV221 Intro Javascript</h2>
        <h3>Comparisons and IF Statements - Odds Evens and Grades</h3>
        <hr />
        <p></p>
        <hr />
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <p>Value 1:
                <input type="text" name="Value1" id="Value1" />
            </p>
            <p>Result: <span id="Result"></span></p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Is it Odd or Even?" onclick="OddEven()"/>
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <h4>Enter the percentage that you have achieved:</h4>
            <p> Percentage:
                <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent" />
            </p>
            <p>Grade: <span id="Score"></span></p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" value="Calculate Grade" onclick="ConvertGrade()"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="button" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm()"/>
            </p>
        </form>

        <p>Instructions:</p>
        <ol>
            <li>You are asked to create a working example in Javascript based upon the two given problems.</li>
            <li>For each problem you have two deliverables:</li>
            <li>Pseudo code algorithm and test plan.</li>
            <li>A working example using Javascript.</li>
            <li>The two problems you have been asked to resolve:</li>
            <li>Get an input value, verify that it is a number, if it is a number determine whether it is even or odd.</li>
            <li>Find the letter grade based upon the percentage grade.   example: 54% is an 'F', 88% is a 'B', etc. This would be a good one to consider using a switch statement.</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>

    function ResetForm()
{
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Grade").innerHTML;
}

function OddEven() {
    //read in entered values from text fields
    var Num1 = document.getElementById("Value1").value;

        if (Num1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Even";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Odd";
        }
}

function ConvertGrade()
{

    var grade = document.getElementById("percent").value;

    {
        case (grade >= 93.0 && grade <= 100):
            LetterGrade = "A";
            break;
        case (grade >= 92.9 && grade <= 90.0):
            LetterGrade = "A-";
            break;
        case (grade >= 89.9 && grade <= 87.0):
            LetterGrade = "B+";
            break;
        case (grade >= 86.9 && grade <= 83.0):
            LetterGrade = "B";
            break;
        case (grade >= 82.9 && grade <= 80.0):
            LetterGrade = "B-";
            break;
        case (grade >= 79.9 && grade <= 70.0):
            LetterGrade = "C";
            break;
        case (grade >= 69.9 && grade <= 60.0):
            LetterGrade = "D";
            break;
        case (grade >= 59.9 && grade <= 0):
            LetterGrade = "F";
            break;
        default:
            LetterGrade = "Enter valid Number"
    }
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = LetterGrade;

}
```

Comment: To start with, `.value` returns a *string*, best to convert it to a number first

Comment: check your id value. `Score` vs `score`

Comment: And you forgot the keyword `switch`. Copy paste error?

Comment: The missing switch statement is a copy paste error, sorry about that.   However it only displays the default selection from the switch statement and no other value no matter what number I enter.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

- As *@rlemon* has pointed out, you have a `span` with `id="Score"` but you try to find it under `score` (note the letter case) in `ConvertGrade()` and under `Grade` in `ResetForm()`.
- The `switch` statement is missing the `switch` keyword and the corresponding expression. I guess you wanted to use `switch (true)`.
- The conditions in each `case` inside the `switch` are the other way around:

```
grade >= 92.9 && grade <= 90.0
// no number is greater than 92.9 and smaller than 90.0
```

- If you are using `<=` and `>=` it is pointless to set the limits in 93 and 92.9. Instead, do  `>= 93` and  `< 93`.
- Actually, you don't need event that. You are using the `break` statement, so it is not necessary to set the upper and lower limit on each `case`. Set just the lower one.
- There is no validation for the data provided in `Value1` to check if the value is actually a number. (thank you *@A.Meshu*)
- You are not cleaning the `score` element in `ResetForm()` (I already pointed out that you named it `Grade`, now I mean that you forgot `= ''` after `innerHTML`.

One extra tip. There are several conventions to write the name of HTML attributes and JavaScript variables. I'm not going to recommend you any. I just advise you to choose one and stick to it. It will save you headaches in the future.

Your code should look afterwards like in the snippet below:

```js
function ResetForm() {
  document.getElementById("form1").reset();
  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "";
}

function OddEven() {
  //read in entered values from text fields
  var Num1 = document.getElementById("Value1").value;

  if (Number.isInteger(+Num1)) {
    if (Num1 % 2 == 0) {
      document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Even";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Odd";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Not a integer";
  }
}

function ConvertGrade() {
  var grade = document.getElementById("percent").value;

  switch (true) {
    case (grade >= 93.0):
      LetterGrade = "A";
      break;
    case (grade >= 90.0):
      LetterGrade = "A-";
      break;
    case (grade >= 87.0):
      LetterGrade = "B+";
      break;
    case (grade >= 83.0):
      LetterGrade = "B";
      break;
    case (grade >= 80.0):
      LetterGrade = "B-";
      break;
    case (grade >= 70.0):
      LetterGrade = "C";
      break;
    case (grade >= 60.0):
      LetterGrade = "D";
      break;
    case (grade >= 0):
      LetterGrade = "F";
      break;
    default:
      LetterGrade = "Enter valid Number"
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = LetterGrade;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>Value 1:
    <input type="text" name="Value1" id="Value1" />
  </p>
  <p>Result: <span id="Result"></span></p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Is it Odd or Even?" onclick="OddEven()" />
  </p>
  <p>
  </p>
  <h4>Enter the percentage that you have achieved:</h4>
  <p> Percentage:
    <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent" />
  </p>
  <p>Grade: <span id="score"></span></p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Grade" onclick="ConvertGrade()" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm()" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice one. i would add to the odd/even conditions another "if" - in case the input is not a number at all. Right now it's pre define all strings as "odd".

Comment: @A.Meshu - thank you, good catch. I would check if the input is an integer. Because odd/even makes sense just with integers and because to include other numeric types is both [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18082/5247200) and [subjective](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2960#issuecomment-212653472). That's why jQuery will deprecate `isNumeric()` in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

> I think your switch syntax is incorrect.

```
switch(expression) {
case x:
    code block
    break;
case y:
    code block
    break;
default:
    code block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other users have written about some of the other issues with your code so I won't repeat that, but I do want to write about your use of `switch`.

While you may have been advised that `switch` might make a good control here, for your purposes `if` conditions are much more suitable and shorter. `switch` has often been adapted for other cases (often seen where `switch (true)` and where the cases are tests against statements to be resolved, not single values like [the documentation suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)), but I think it's wrong.

So here's a break down of how a series of `if` conditions can do a better job than a `switch` in this situation. Hope it's of some use.

```js
// pick up the container elements
const q1 = document.querySelector('#q1');
const q2 = document.querySelector('#q2');

// attach change listeners to the input boxes
q1.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', handleOddEven, false);
q2.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', handlePercentage, false);

function oddEven(n) {

  // ternary operator which says
  // if the modulo of 2 is 0 return even, otherwise odd
  return n % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}

function findLetterGrade(n) {
  let grade = 'A';

  // drop through the conditions to match the grade
  if (n <= 93) grade = 'A-';
  if (n <= 90) grade = 'B';
  if (n <= 87) grade = 'B-';
  if (n <= 83) grade = 'C';
  if (n <= 80) grade = 'D';
  if (n <= 70) grade = 'E';
  if (n <= 60) grade = 'F';
  return grade;
}

function handlePercentage() {

  // coerce the string value to a number
  const val = parseInt(this.value, 10);

  // add the returned result from findLetterGrade to the
  // textContent of the corresponding span
  q2.querySelector('span').textContent = findLetterGrade(val);
}

function handleOddEven() {
  const val = parseInt(this.value, 10);

  // is the value a number?
  const isNumber = !Number.isNaN(val);
  let txt;
  if (isNumber) {
    txt = `This is a number. It is ${oddEven(val)}`;
  } else {
    txt = 'This is not a number';
  }
  q1.querySelector('span').textContent = txt;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1"><input type="text" placeholder="Add number" /><span></span></div>
<div id="q2"><input type="text" placeholder="Add percentage" /><span></span></div>
```